# Why does Firefox always give a warning with CSP: default-src 'self'?

Tags: security, web, content-security-policy

If I serve the following html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>CSP test</title>
</head>
<body>
  Surely I'm too simple to need a complicated CSP?!?
</body>
</html>
```

with the following header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

Firefox (version 77.0.1 and earlier, macOS 10.15) *always* prints this error in the console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("default-src").
```

This despite the fact that this content security policy is the first example on the [MDN page about content security policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) where it is presented as the policy for the exact use case I have. Chrome does not print any such error message. Is this a Firefox bug or am I overlooking some subtlety?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something's not right here.  The HTML you present should not present a CSP error. Look at source and see what's actually being served to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response @StephenR . Just checked the response using Firefox's developer tools (the network tab) and it is verbatim what I've written.

Comment: Turn off all browser add-ons and see what happens

Comment: You've nailed it @StephenR! When they were all disabled, no warning. Also, I didn't have any browser extensions in the Chrome I was using. Looks like Troy Hunt has [posted](https://www.troyhunt.com/add-ons-extensions-and-csp-violations-playing-nice-with-content-security-policies/) about this in the past. Do you want to actually answer the questions so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t see anything wrong in your code, so it’s likely some thing else.

Try turning off all browser add-ons. Sometimes those can trigger CSP errors

Comment: browser's plugins can trigger CSP warnings because some of them (like React Dev Tools) modify the DOM and could load external scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some information to the answer regarding Firefox browser extensions being to blame, in my case it was the React Developer Tools extension that caused this to appear.